# Solving a recursive equations with the tree method

Tags: abstract-algebra, recursion

I have the following recursion formula: 
$$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+aT\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+n^{2}$$
where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $T(n)=1$ for $n<10$. In the solutions is suggested to use the tree method to calculate that on the left path we get $n^{2}\sum_{i=0}^{log_{4}n}(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{a}{16})$ and on the right path we get $n^{2}\sum_{i=0}^{log_{2}n}(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{a}{16})$. I don't understand why and will be glad to get an explanation.
Also, Is it true to say that for:
$$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)+aT\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)+n^{2}$$
where $k,m\in\mathbb{N}$ we get on the left path we get $n^{2}\sum_{i=0}^{log_{m}n}(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{a}{16})$ and on the right path we get $n^{2}\sum_{i=0}^{log_{k}n}(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{a}{16})$?

Comment: It is $$T_n=\frac{c_1 \left(1-\sqrt{4 a+1}\right)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}}{n}+\frac{c_2
   \left(\sqrt{4 a+1}+1\right)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}}{n}+\frac{16 a \left(1-\sqrt{4
   a+1}\right)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}} \left(\sqrt{4 a+1}+1\right)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log
   (2)}} (-a)^{-\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}}{\left(-a+2 \sqrt{4 a+1}-2\right) \left(a+2
   \sqrt{4 a+1}+2\right)}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, can you please explain what do you mean?